# How do I read a swift file from system as config file much like Swift Package Manager?

Tags: swift, command-line-tool

I am creating a command line tool, using Swift in Xcode.  I would like to use a config file much like [grunt](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks) does, but I want it to be swift code like the Swift Package Manager's `package.swift` file.

My question is:  Can I have a swift config file that I can read from disk and have access to variables in it much like it had been imported before compiling?

To clarify, the config file will be created by users of my utility to configure how my utility should behave.  I would like that file to use swift code to declare variables of all kinds so that I can read those variables cleanly in my swift code.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

This may not answer your question in exactly the same way you want but it may help you achieve what you want in an alternative way.

you can provide a template for others to configure your parameter file like below

```
IN_VER_APP="1.5.10"
USERNAME="admin"
PASSWORD="test"
```

and request them to save it in a file say "InputFile.txt"

Then next create sh file which will be responsible for sourcing this file and your tool. your sh file content can look like below

```
source InputFile.txt
./YourTool "${USERNAME}" "${PASSWORD}" "${IN_VER_APP}"
```

Now in your swift tool, you can receive these arguments in your using below as an array and in sequence.

```
let arguments = CommandLine.arguments
let username = arguments[0]
let password = arguments[1]
let version = arguments[2]
```

Now you have to just run your sh file to launch your tool which will read your input file to provide parameters to your swift command line tool

Comment: Yes, that would work. It's just not as elegant as I would like.  I had thought about json.  The problem is, that I've already seen Swift Package Manager already doing exactly what I think I want, so it must be possible.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, your configuration need to conform to Decodable, then you need to compile swift configuration file then you can read the data at runtime:

```
 // MARK: - Private
private func loadManifest<T: Decodable>(_ manifest: Manifest, at path: AbsolutePath) throws -> T {
    let manifestPath = path.appending(component: manifest.fileName)
    guard FileHandler.shared.exists(manifestPath) else {
        throw GraphManifestLoaderError.manifestNotFound(manifest, path)
    }
    let data = try loadManifestData(at: manifestPath)
    return try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
}

private func loadManifestData(at path: AbsolutePath) throws -> Data {
    let projectDescriptionPath = try resourceLocator.projectDescription()
    var arguments: [String] = [
        "/usr/bin/xcrun",
        "swiftc",
        "--driver-mode=swift",
        "-suppress-warnings",
        "-I", projectDescriptionPath.parentDirectory.pathString,
        "-L", projectDescriptionPath.parentDirectory.pathString,
        "-F", projectDescriptionPath.parentDirectory.pathString,
        "-lProjectDescription",
    ]
    arguments.append(path.pathString)
    arguments.append("--dump")

    guard let jsonString = try System.shared.capture(arguments).spm_chuzzle(),
        let data = jsonString.data(using: .utf8) else {
        throw GraphManifestLoaderError.unexpectedOutput(path)
    }

    return data
```

This is example from [Tuist project](https://github.com/tuist/tuist/blob/47505e679c07b7ec416f49c4f568897ff076c953/Sources/TuistKit/Generator/GraphManifestLoader.swift).